# Why would changes in jet-engine power settings not result in changes in engine loudness?

Tags: jet-engine, noise

My casual AAR reading has dredged up another counterintuitive detail of aircraft behaviour, this time regarding the relationship between engine power and engine loudness:

> **1.16.7.3 Sound Similar to Airplane Engines Increasing in Loudness**
>
> **A review of the sound signatures associated with the rotating engines recorded by USAir flight 427’s CVR revealed that, throughout the 31-minute CVR recording, the engine’s sound signatures changed in frequency as the engine speed increased or decreased but remained constant in intensity (volume).** During the upset sequence, the CAM channel of the accident CVR also recorded variations in the volume of the sound signatures associated with the engines. ***The sound spectrum study indicated that, at 1902:58.27 and 1903:02.3, the sounds on the CVR recording that were associated with both engines simultaneously increased in volume by about 30 percent; at the same time, the frequency of the engine sound signatures, and the volume of all other background noises, remained constant.*** The first increase signature occurred about 0.17 seconds after the first thump in the second set of thump sounds; the second increase occurred about 1 second later, just before the captain exclaimed “hang on.” **Although FDR data indicated that the engine power settings changed during the accident sequence,<sup>201</sup> the engine sounds (when identifiable) remained at the increased volume throughout the remainder of the CVR recording.**
>
> ---
>
> <sup>201</sup> The FDR data indicated that, after a brief increase in engine power setting at 1903:02, the engine power settings began to decrease from the peak power setting recorded during the accident sequence (about 80 percent N1); by 1903:09, the engine power settings had decreased to about 30 percent N1, at which point they remained until ground impact.  *[[NTSB/AAR-99/01](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR9901.pdf), page 132 (page 156 of the PDF).  Section heading bolded in original; all other emphasis mine.  **Bolding** emphasises that engine loudness generally remained constant despite changes in engine power;* **bold italics** *emphasise that the changes in loudness that* did *occur did* not *correspond to changes in engine power.<sup>1</sup>]*

One would generally expect jet-engine loudness to correspond closely to engine power, for the following reasons (and quite possibly more as well):

- At higher power settings, a much greater volume of air is forced through the engine and compressed and heated to a much greater degree than at low power settings, producing higher levels of engine airflow and increased tailpipe outlet pressure (observable in the cockpit as an increase in EPR, for engines so equipped), which one would expect to create more sound.
- At higher power settings, the fan and compressor blades move faster and hit the incoming air harder, and the superheated gasses coming out of the combustion chamber move faster and hit the turbine blades harder, than at low power settings, which one would expect to create more sound.
- At higher power settings, the core-exhaust jet is hotter and travelling faster than at low power settings, causing it to generate more vigorous turbulence for longer at its boundary with the bypass airflow, and the bypass air itself is hotter (due to undergoing a greater degree of compression from the faster-moving-and-harder-hitting fan blades) and faster-moving than at low power settings, causing *it* to generate more vigorous turbulence for longer at its boundary with the ambient air.  As turbulence at the interfaces of the differently-fast flow streams is a major source of noise (especially for engines not equipped with [exhaust mixers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaust_mixer)), one would expect the increase in said turbulence at higher power settings to create more sound.
- At higher power settings, more fuel is entering the combustion chamber and burning than at low power settings, which releases a greater amount of energy in so doing, which one would expect to create more sound.

Indeed, at very low engine speeds (for instance, when starting or shutting down an engine), a change in engine power *does* result in the expected change in loudness.  So why would the loudness of an engine in flight *not* depend on its power setting?

---

<sup>1</sup>: The anomalous increases in engine loudness were eventually deemed to reflect increased levels of fan noise resulting from alteration of engine-intake airflow due to the large sideslip angle attained by the aircraft during the accident sequence.